# Using password_hash PASSWORD_DEFAULT legacy concerns

Tags: php, database, cryptography

From the php page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> **PASSWORD_DEFAULT** - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

Would this mean that if I `password_verify` a password with a later version e.g. PHP8, it might not be able to decipher the stored password correctly? Or is all that information safely embedded already and all I have to do is store the output of `password_hash` into my DB and just call `password_verify` for validation without worries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the information is safely embedded, *provided that your database doesn't truncate the encrypted password*. Which is pretty much a given, I'd think.

What that warning is driving home is that, for your future self's sanity, you store the information in a field whose length is flexible. Historically, like with MD5, one might have chosen `CHAR(32)`. But with bcrypt, you need to choose something more flexible. That might be:

- `VARCHAR(255)`
- `CHAR(60)`, with this column being the *last* one in the table, so that extending its length might not require the RDBMS to reshuffle table.

Comment: I'm using mariadb and I have the field type as text. Is that okay?

Comment: Unbounded `TEXT` is overkill, I'd go with `VARCHAR` or a bounded `TEXT`, like `TEXT(255)`.

Answer (score 3):

> Would this mean that if I `password_verify` a password with a later version e.g. PHP8, it might not be able to decipher the stored password correctly?

No. The password hash includes information on which specific algorithm was actually used. If a future version of PHP supports more than one password hashing algorithm, it will be able to read that information from an old hash to figure out how to reproduce it.

(Specifically, the `$2y$` prefix currently present on all hashes indicates that they were generated using the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` algorithm. Any future algorithm will use a different prefix.)